# Are these two C# statements identical?

Tags: c#

Items is a `List<Item>` of Items, one of the properties of which is ID.

```
   public static Item ItemByID(int id)
   {
       foreach (Item item in Items)
       {
           if (item.ID == id)
           {
               return item;
           }
       }
       return null;
   }
```

And:

```
public static Item ItemByID(int id)
{
     return Items.FirstOrDefault(item => item.ID == id);
}
```

I think it is but I am not sure `FirstOrDefault()` will return null if it doesn't find it.

Comment: What do you think `OrDefault` means?

Comment: They don't produce the same IL.  And there *may* be subtle differences in performance or other metrics depending on what `Items` is and how it enumerates.  *But*, yes, logically these two things achieve the same result.

Comment: What if Item has a constructor that defines a default value for it?

Comment: @SpenceW hun? The `default` of a reference type (such as a Class) is null.

Comment: Instead of returning `null`, you could return `default(Item)`.  By the way, they aren't _identical_ by my understanding of _identical_; they are very different, but they are semantically nearly the same

Comment: @SpenceW: Instead of asking such hypotheticals and trying to move the target of the question, *test* it.

Comment: Thanks for the responses everyone.  I'll test it just to make sure.

Comment: Did you check the documentation on [the `Enumerable.FirstOrDefault` overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.firstordefault?view=net-6.0#system-linq-enumerable-firstordefault-1(system-collections-generic-ienumerable((-0))-system-func((-0-system-boolean)))) you are calling? See also [default value expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/default).

Comment: Also I apologize if I was unclear.  I just wanted to make sure that FirstOrDefault would always return null if it couldn't find the Item, which seems to be the case.

Comment: Yes, that's what it's [documented to do](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.firstordefault?view=net-6.0#system-linq-enumerable-firstordefault-1(system-collections-generic-ienumerable((-0))-system-func((-0-system-boolean))-0)), assuming your source is a reference type.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the two blocks of code function the same way.